# How to know weather request in new or old in play 2.x framework?

Tags: java, playframework, play2-mini

In play 1.x framework, there is a method under play.mvc.Http.Request class isNew(), which identifies whether the request is new or old. In play 2.x there is no such method available. Can anyone tell the alternative for isNew method for the above task?

Comment: To me this method seems pretty much useless, it only tracks if a request has been transmitted earlier or not. In most cases that's not a piece of information you'd need. If you do, consider wrapping the request in some class that keeps track of whether its been sent or not

Comment: yes, I did the same. Thanks @martijnp